# Why are microservices not restarted on GKE - "failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, skaffold

I'm running microservices on GKE and using skaffold for management.

Everything works fine for a week and suddenly all services are killed (not sure why).

Logging shows this same info for all services:

[image]

There is no indication that something is going wrong in the logs before all services fail. It looks like the pods are all killed at the same time by GKE for whatever reason.

What confuses me is why the services do not restart.
`kubectl describe pod auth` shows a "imagepullbackoff" error.

When I simulate this situation on the test system (same setup) by deleting a pod manually, all services restart just fine.

To deploy the microservices, I use skaffold.

*---deployment.yaml for one of the microservices---*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
  namespace: development
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          secret:
            secretName: pubsub-key
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: us.gcr.io/XXXX/auth
          volumeMounts:
            - name: google-cloud-key
              mountPath: /var/secrets/google
          env:
            - name: NATS_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: NATS_URL
              value: 'http://nats-srv:4222'
            - name: NATS_CLUSTER_ID
              value: XXXX
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
            - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
              value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
```

Any idea why the microservices don't restart? Again, they run fine after deploying them with skaffold and also after simulating pod shutdown on the test system ... what changed here?

---- Update 2021.10.30 -------------

After some further digging in the cloud log explorer, I figured out that the pod is trying to pull the previously build image but fails. If I pull the image on cloud console manually using the image name plus tag as listed in the logs, it works just fine (thus the image is there).

The log gives the following reason for the error:

`Failed to pull image "us.gcr.io/scout-productive/client:v0.002-72-gaa98dde@sha256:383af5c5989a3e8a5608495e589c67f444d99e7b705cfff29e57f49b900cba33": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "us.gcr.io/scout-productive/client@sha256:383af5c5989a3e8a5608495e589c67f444d99e7b705cfff29e57f49b900cba33": failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:4e9f2cdf438714c2c4533e28c6c41a89cc6c1b46cf77e54c488db30ca4f5b6f3 (application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip) from remote: not found"`

Where is that `"sha256:4e9f2cdf438714c2c4533e28c6c41a89cc6c1b46cf77e54c488db30ca4f5b6f3"` coming from that it cannot find according to the error message?

Any help/pointers are much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `imagepullbackoff` means that kubernetes couldn't download the images from the registry - that could mean that the image with that name/tag doesn't exist, OR the the credentials to the registry is wrong/expired.

From what I see in your `deployment.yml` there aren't provided any credentials to the registry at all. You can do it by providing `imagePullSecret`. I never used Skaffold, but my assumptions is that you login to private registry in Skaffold, and use it to deploy the images, so when Kubernetes tries to redownload the image from the registry by itself, it fails because because of lack of  authorization.

I can propose two solutions:

**1. ImagePullSecret**

You can create **secret** resource witch will contain credentials to private registry, then define that secret in the `deployment.yml`, that way Kubernetes will be able to authorize at your private registry and pull the images.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

**2. ImagePullPolicy**

You can prevent re-downloading your images, by setting `ImagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent` in the `deployment.yml` . It will reuse the one which is available locally. Using this method requires defining image tags properly. For example using this with `:latest` tag can lead to not pulling the "newest latest" image, because from cluster perspective, it already has image with that tag so it won't download a new one.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy

To resolve problem with pods being killed, can you share Kubernetes events from the time when pods are being killed? `kubectl -n NAMESPACE get events` This would maybe give more information.

Comment: Just a note that GKE clusters are automatically configured to pull from GCR and GCR and Artifact Registry repositories in the same project.  And the default `imagePullPolicy` for images with a tag is `IfNotPresent` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullpolicy-defaulting).  The error suggests that a new node may have been created since images are cached on the node.

Comment: @Brian de Alwis.   Thanks for the reply. A new node was created by GKE as the old one needed maintenance and thus the cached copy was removed too. I'm certain that the system did not attempt to build the image but tried to pull it from the container registry. In said registry, I see entries with the correct name and tag v0.002-72-gaa98dde. I can also pull the image manually in cloud console. But I can't figure out why the new node failed to pull it. It should not be a permission thing as the deployment worked initially when I started the nodes/microservices up with skaffold.

Comment: Note that when an image digest is specified, the tag is ignored.  So it's important to check whether an image with the `sha256:383af5c5989a3e8a5608495e589c67f444d99e7b705cfff29e57f49b900cba33` digest is listed (I'm guessing: no).

Answer (score 0):

When Skaffold causes an image to be built, the image is pushed to a repository (`us.gcr.io/scout-productive/client`) using a tag generated with your specified *tagging policy* (`v0.002-72-gaa98dde`; this tag looks like the result of using Skaffold's default [`gitCommit` tagging policy](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/taggers/#gitcommit-uses-git-commitsreferences-as-tags)). The remote registry returns the *image digest* of the received image, a SHA256 value computed from the image metadata and image file contents (`sha256:383af5c5989a3e8a5608495e589c67f444d99e7b705cfff29e57f49b900cba33`). The image digest is unique like a fingerprint, whereas a tag is just `name → image digest` mapping, and which may be updated to point to a different image digest.

When deploying your application, Skaffold rewrites your manifests on-the-fly to reference the specific built container images by using both the generated tag and the image digest.  Container runtimes ignore the image tag when an image digest is specified since the digest identifies a unique image.

---

So the fact that your specific image cannot be resolved means that the image has been deleted from your repository.  Are you, or someone on your team, deleting images?

Some people run *image garbage collectors* to delete old images.  Skaffold users do this to delete the interim images generated by `skaffold dev` between dev loops.  But some of these collectors are indiscriminate, such as only keeping images tagged with `latest`.  Since Skaffold tags images using a configured tagging policy, such collectors can delete your Skaffold-built images.  To avoid problems, either tune your collector (e.g., only deleted untagged images), or have Skaffold build your dev and production images to different repositories.  For example, GCP's [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr) allows having multiple independent repositories in the same project, and your GKE cluster can access all such repositories.